# Changing my default directory in passwd changes my prompt

Tags: shell, password, prompt

I don't understand what's happening in this scenario.

I changed the home directory of a user by editing the `/etc/passwd` file instead of using `usermod -d`. It worked: the default directory wasn't `/home/nameoftheuser` anymore, but `/data/nameoftheuser`, as I wanted.

But something else changed: the prompt of the user. It isn't `[\u@\h \W]\$` like it used to be. Now it's just `bash 3.2` or something, and yet when I check `$PS1`, it's still `[\u@\h \W]\$`. `$PS2` thru `$PS4` are either empty or totally different from `\v`.

Now, if I change `/etc/passwd` back to the default, the prompt returns to normal.

Can anyone tell me why this happens?

Comment: Never move `/home`.  The system expects this directory to be there, for things like `$HOME`

Comment: What OS is this? Also, please add the output of `ls -ld /data/nameoftheuser` to the question. (Feel free to sanitize it. I need to see the permissions.)

Comment: @eyoung100: No. User directories can be anywhere on the system. The whole point of having a user database like `/etc/passwd` (but not limited to it; e.g. LDAP) is to allow you to change things like a user's home directory.

Comment: @WarrenYoung I agree there, but I feel differently in that `/home/user` is a system default.  I've seen people move `/home` to a different partition but never have I seen it replaced.

Comment: @eyoung100: Yes, well, I *have*. One system I used had about 9,000 real users on it, back in the day when many people sharing a single machine made sense. They simply couldn't fit every user's home directory onto a single physical hard disk, so the home directory scheme looked something like `/u1/fred`, `/u1/barney`, `/u2/wilma`, etc. Whether you got onto `/u1`, `/u2`, or whatever depended mainly on how early you first signed onto the system.

Comment: @WarrenYoung And that is why I'm here... to learn tidbits like this...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17378/discussion-between-warren-young-and-eyoung100).

Comment: Well, the same programming idiocy that hardcodes paths in Win programs also exists in some unixoid software. I don't recall what it was (maybe old versions of Opera), but something assumed that `/home/(username)/` existed and was writable. Little harm in having a symlink to be on the safe side.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you copied .bashrc file from the old home directory to the new one?. If you don't that is the problem, you don't have the environment variables set. Check that HOME is set there though, if it wasn't set there then it is being taken from /etc/bash.bashrc, so you should set the new one in the .bashrc that you are going to place in your new home.

Comment: Thanks I did not copied bashrc indeed. That was the problem. Thanks :)